# Не открывается Web App telegram внутри бота

Tags: python, telegram, nginx, https, aiogram-3.x

Написал бота, который по кнопке должен открывать web app. Web app - по сути просто html страница. Подключен https. На айфоне все прекрасно работает, но на андроидах не открывает (проверил на 4х устройствах). Просто появляется окно web app, но без контента. Прошу подсказать с чем может быть связано

Вот кнопка (aiogram 3.x):
InlineKeyboardButton(text='Читать', web_app=WebAppInfo(url='https://amadeusx.ru/chapters/1'))

Узнал, что запрос даже не приходит на сервер, будто вовсе не отправляется

Бот: AmadeusMangaBot

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы можете, пожалуйста, показать код? Без кода ответы будут основаны на мнениях и могут оказаться неверными. Отредактировав вопрос, добавив код, вы тем самым привлечёте больше внимания и появится больше желания ответить на вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решается заменой ssl сертификатов

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.